# select same column twice having different values for single id using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these three tables movies, category and relationship as shown below.

```
movies--
-----------------------
id|name|duration|
1 |x   |5 mins  |
2 |y   |10 mins |
----------------------
category--
-----------------------
id|type    |value    |
1 |genre   |action   |
2 |language|english  |
3 |genre   |thriller |
4 |language|spanish  |
------------------------

relationship--
id| movie_id|category_id|
1 |1        |        2  |
2 |1        |        3  |
------------------------------
```

i want a query that will fetch both genre and language for the movie in a single query.

below is the expected output.

```
name|duration|language|genre   |
x   |5 mins  |english |thriller|
--------------------------------
```

in short i want to use the type column twice.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need mysql pivot table for that. That is turn some columns into row data. The following query will produce what you want:

```
SELECT
  m.name,
  m.duration,
  MAX(IF(c.type = 'language', c.value, NULL)) AS language,
  MAX(IF(c.type = 'genre', c.value, NULL)) AS genre
FROM movies AS m
INNER JOIN relationship AS r ON m.id = r.movie_id
INNER JOIN category AS c ON r.category_id = c.id
WHERE m.name = 'x'
GROUP BY m.name;
```

That will produce:

```
| name | duration | language | genre    |
| x    | 5 mins   | english  | thriller |
```

See **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4c524/4)**

Comment: I want to add to this. if i try to filter genre(like where c.value='thriller'), i get expected number of rows but I get language column as null. please help

Comment: @iamP it is because we do the selection in one query and the language and genre are in the same table (category). So if you do select `c.value = 'thriller'` you only select the genre of the movie, and not the language row. For a quick solution you need to change the above query to be: `SELECT * FROM (above query here) AS x WHERE genre = 'thriller'`. See modified [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f4c524/12).

Answer (score 1):

- Step 1: Join all the three table together. Now you get all the category infos for each movie.
- Step 2: Select what you want from the big combined table.
- Step 3: Use two subquery to satisfy your special needs for `language` and `genre`.
- Step 4: Add a `LIMIT 1` to avoid redundant records.

The final query might be something like this:

```
SELECT name, duration, (SELECT value FROM t WHERE type = 'language' AND name = 'x') AS language, (SELECT value FROM t WHERE type = 'genre' AND name = 'x') AS genre
FROM 
(
  SELECT m.name, m.duration, c.type FROM movies AS m
  JOIN relationship AS r ON m.id = r.movie_id
  JOIN category AS c ON r.category_id = c.id
) AS t LIMIT 1;
```

Note:

1. Replace your own query condition for `WHERE` clause.
2. This query might not be strictly syntax correct. Please fix it by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses two joins, one for each type:

```
select m.*, cl.value as language, cg.language as genre
from movies m join
     relationships r
     on m.id = r.movie_id left join
     categories cl
     on cl.id = r.category_id and type = 'language' left join
     categories cg
     on cg.id = r.category_id and type = 'genre';
```

Note that movies typically have only one language, but they can have multiple genres.  If this is the case you will get a separate row for each genre.

Comment: i get  two rows where in one row has null language and other has null genre using your query